# Me repite el resultado por cada carácter de la cadena

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa que lea el número de vocales, pero se me repite el resultado por cada carácter de la cadena.

Éste es el código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner text = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Por favor escriba un texto: ");
    String palabra;
    palabra = text.nextLine();

    char arreglo []  = palabra.toCharArray();

    int conta =0;  

    for (int count=0;count<arreglo.length;count++){
        if ((palabra.charAt(count)=='a')|| (palabra.charAt(count)=='A')||(palabra.charAt(count)=='e')
        ||(palabra.charAt(count)=='E')|| (palabra.charAt(count)=='i') || (palabra.charAt(count)=='I') 
        || (palabra.charAt(count)=='o') || (palabra.charAt(count)=='O') || (palabra.charAt(count)=='u')
        || (palabra.charAt(count)=='U')){
            conta++;
        }          
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < arreglo.length;count++) {

        System.out.println("han sido ingresados: "+conta+" vocales");
    }
}
```

Y este es el resultado que obtengo:

[image: resultado]

Comment: Hola Joseph Davison, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bienvenido a Stackoverflow:

Se te repite el resultado porque en el bucle final, haces que por cada carácter de la palabra insertada, te imprima el número de vocales que contiene toda la palabra.

Por tanto te sobra ese bucle final. Dejándolo así te imprime el número de vocales correcto y lo indica por la salida estándar una única vez:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner text = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Por favor escriba un texto: ");
  String palabra = "hugo";
  //palabra = text.nextLine();

  char arreglo[] = palabra.toCharArray();

  int conta = 0;

  for (int count = 0; count < arreglo.length; count++) {
   if ((palabra.charAt(count) == 'a') || (palabra.charAt(count) == 'A') || (palabra.charAt(count) == 'e') || (palabra.charAt(count) == 'E') || (palabra.charAt(count) == 'i') || (palabra.charAt(count) == 'I') || (palabra.charAt(count) == 'o') || (palabra.charAt(count) == 'O') || (palabra.charAt(count) == 'u') || (palabra.charAt(count) == 'U')) {
    conta++;
   }
  }

  //for (int count = 0; count < arreglo.length;count++) {

  System.out.println("han sido ingresados: " + conta + " vocales");
  //}
 }
}
```

La salida sería:

```
$javac HelloWorld.java 
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M HelloWorld  
Por favor escriba un texto:  
han sido ingresados: 2 vocales
```

Para la palabra hugo.